# Find the exact value of $\cot(202.5^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

As the title states.

I've hardly touched trig before, and finally wrapped my head around how to find $\displaystyle\cos(225^\circ), \tan(405^\circ),$ etc, but I don't get how to find $\displaystyle\cot(202.5^\circ)$.

Please help explain very clearly.

Please help explain very clearly.

Comment: Degrees or radians?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cot(202.5^0) = \cot(180^0+22.5^0) = \cot (22.5^0)$$

Now Calculate value of $\displaystyle \tan (22.5^0)$

Using $$\displaystyle \tan(2A) = \frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2 A}\;,$$ Put $A=22.5^0$

We get $$\displaystyle \tan (45^0) = \frac{2\tan (22.5^0)}{1-\tan^2(22.5^0)}\Rightarrow 2\tan(22.5^0)=1-\tan^2(22.5^0)$$
So we get $$\tan^2(22.5^0)+2\tan(22.5^0)+1 = 2\Rightarrow \left[1+\tan(22.5^0)\right]^2=(\sqrt{2})^2$$

So we get $$\displaystyle 1+\tan(22.5^0) = \pm \sqrt{2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \tan(22.5^0) = \sqrt{2}-1$$ bcz $\tan(22.5^0)>0$

So we get $$\displaystyle \cot(22.5^0) = \frac{1}{\tan(22.5^0)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\times \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1} = \sqrt{2}+1$$

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks. Sorry: Can you explain the 2tan(22.50)=1−tan2(22.50) part for me?

Comment: Here I have Used Double angle formula.

Comment: I see that. I mean how you transitioned to that step. Give me a moment, let me look at it again...

Comment: Here I have Used the formula $a^2+b^2+2ab = (a+b)^2\;,$ Like for $\tan^2(22.5^0)+1+2\tan^2(22.5^0) = (\tan(22.5^0)+1)^2$

Comment: I mean the step before that. How you got from  tan(45)=2tan(22.5)/1−tan2(22.5)
⇒2tan(22.5)=1−tan2(22.5)

Comment: Actually Here I have used double angle formula $\displaystyle \tan(2A) = \frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2 A}\;,$ Then put $A=22.5^0$ and then cross multiply.

Comment: SORRY! I just remembered tan 45 = 1, that's how. I was confused where the tan 45 had gone, not about the formulas and stuff. Thank you for this explanation!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\cot A=\dfrac{2\cos^2A}{2\sin A\cos A}=\dfrac{1+\cos2A}{\sin2A}$$

Now set $A=202.5^\circ$

$2A=405^\circ=360^\circ+45^\circ\implies\cos2A=\cdots=\cos45^\circ\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Can you find $\sin2A?$

Comment: @mathflair, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute it by hand you could use the $\cot z$ series,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n} B_{2n} z^{2n-1}}{(2n!)}$$

Where $B_{2n}$ are Bernoulli numbers. This only works in radians so convert $202.5$ degrees to radians and do a numerical approximation.

It will be pretty accurate (not exact though). Bernoulli numbers are also hard to compute so you can compute a very accurate cosine (using the series) of $202.5$ degrees and divide it by a computation of a very accurate sine of $202.5$ degrees using the series to get a better answer.

Remember convert your degrees to radians.

Answer (score 0):

$\cot 202.5^0 = \cot 22.5 $, in third quadrant. Recognizing half of $45^0$ you are going to need tan of half angle formula.

Denoting tan full angle by caps, $ T = \dfrac{2 t }{1-t^2} \implies t = (\sqrt{ 1+T}-1 ) , \tan 22.5^0 = \sqrt 2 -1$ where we chose positive value from  $\pm$ in third quadrant...and the required cot is its reciprocal:

$$ \cot 22.5^0 = \sqrt 2 +1.$$